# Get count of users group by group and date , laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I  have a subscriber table  where every  subscriber belongs to  one group, which I  identified by  this relation

```
public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ispgroup','id','group_id');
}
```

and I  have another  table that collects the logs for every  subscriber,  like the time that user gets online and the time when the subscriber gets disconnected,  and I  identified  this relationship depending on the username like this

```
public function logs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Logs', 'username', 'username');
}
```

Logs  table has  this structure,

> username ------- online_at(DateTime) ---------
> disconnected_at(DateTime)

I want to  get the count of online users for the last hour group  by group and by minutes,  as I'll show  the graph in minutes

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: I  trıed  but  I  don't know ,  I  could not do  ıt  , and I  am keep  trying but I  nothings that I  can write it here